# sandboxed web parts inside SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sandbox, moss

Is it possible to develop a web-part in ASP.NET (framework > 2.0), to have a sandbox architecture, and deploy those web parts inside Share Point 2010 and/or MOSS 2007

we donot want to use any SharePoint dll reference with web parts we develop.

we refer to the url, section at  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539417.aspx (section Web Parts in Sandboxed Solutions)

Answer (score 0):

i referred the following How Tos, hope it helps some one ..

1. http://blah.winsmarts.com/2009-12-SharePoint_2010_Sandboxed_Solutions__The_basics.aspx
2. _http://www.sharepointdevwiki.com/display/sp2010/SharePoint+Sandboxed+Solutions
3. _http://www.endusersharepoint.com/EUSP2010/2010/04/05/introduction-to-sharepoint-2010-sandbox-solutions-for-site-collection-owners

Answer (score 0):

I've just hit this problem - looks like it's not meant to be possible which is really annoying.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615454.aspx

Specifically:

> Application pages, mobile pages, and user controls (.ascx files) cannot be deployed in a sandboxed solution.

However, there is a workaround (hackaround!) here:

http://stefan-stanev-sharepoint-blog.blogspot.com/2010/02/visual-sandbox-web-parts-possible-after.html

I'd love to have a better way!